# IE Exception if beforeunload event aborts page redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a cancel button that when called redirects the user to another page:

```js
function onCancelButtonClick() { 
   document.location.href = settings.cancelUrl; 
}
```

I also have an event handler for the beforeunload event in order to prompt the user for confirmation before leaving the page if there are unsaved changes:

```js
function onPageUnload() {
  //If the changes were already saved then there is no need to prompt the user for confirmation before leaving the page.
  if (eventDataSaved)
    return;

  //If the page has unsaved changes ask for confirmation before leaving the page.
  if (hasTheGridRecordsBeenChanged() || formHasUnsavedChanges)
    return "You have unsaved changes";
}
```

This works well in chrome. However, IE is throwing an exception in the onCancelButtonClick event handler method whenever the user selects the option of staying in the page when prompted.

I saw a couple of posts in SO from 2009 and 2010 that recommended just adding a try catch to address this which I am sure that we can all agree it's not an ideal solution. So I was wondering if in the past few years someone came up with a more elegant approach to address this IE issue.

Comment: I believe the try/catch is the only solution for IE in this situation - and most likely will be forever now it's out of support. I'll happily be proved wrong though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So since in my case I wanted to redirect the user back to the page that they were coming from I found out that if I leverage the browser history (as opposed to redirecting the user using document.location.href) IE no longer throws an exception.

So for me the solution was just to use window.history.back()  However you can also go to specific pages that were previously visited without getting an exception using window.history.go()  so the only scenario where you would still encounter the IE issue that I mentioned in my question is if your user tries to go to a page that s/he has not visited recently.